# How should I append all my results to one list after each iteration in the python?

Tags: python

```
def pascalstriangle(n):
    list = [1]
    for i in range(n):
        print(list)
        newlist = []
        newlist.append(list[0])
        for i in range(len(list) - 1):
            newlist.append(list[i] + list[i + 1])
        newlist.append(list[-1])
        list = newlist
print(pascalstriangle(3))
```

I want to see this print format `[1,1,1,1,2,1]` instead of

```
[1] 
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the above code, whenever you are printing `list` you can add those to other list (*in below code adding them to `final_list` with `extend`*) and finally return it at end of the function:

```
def pascalstriangle(n):
    list = [1]
    final_list = []

    for i in range(n):
        final_list.extend(list)
        newlist = []
        newlist.append(list[0])
        for i in range(len(list) - 1):
            newlist.append(list[i] + list[i + 1])
        newlist.append(list[-1])
        list = newlist
    return final_list

print(pascalstriangle(3))
```

Result:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
```

*One thing you may want to consider is not using `list` as variable and using somethin like `my_list`.*

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two lists in Python like this:

```
print([1, 2] + [3])
> [1, 2, 3]
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just merge two lists :

```
final_list = list1 + list2
```

Comment: Have you tried applying this to the OP's code? For small examples it might be manageable but for larger examples it is not. And their current logic requires that `list` be reassigned on each loop, so a straightforward application of this principle is not clear in your answer.